# Error al declarar variable dentro de una sentencia de declaracion de clase

Tags: c#, variables

estoy iniciandome en la programacion en c#,

No puedo utilizar las variables dentro de la clase "no Existe en el contexto actual" , como las puedo utilizar?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1{

  class clasePrueba{

     private String persona;
     string nombre;

     persona;
  }
}
```

Comment: "*El nombre 'persona' no existe en el contexto actual.*" Intenta poner la variable en una función, no en la zona de declaración de variables. Y por favor: esta es una página sobre código, no sobre capturas de pantalla ¿Por qué poner capturas en lugar de código? ¡es más complicado! y no se puede copiapegar el código de una imagen ni hacer búsquedas de texto; por favor: **PON EL CÓDIGO**, **NO IMÁGENES**.

Comment: No puedes acceder a una variable desde el cuerpo de la clase. Debes crear un método y ahi ya tendrás acceso. Por cierto, en .net el standard indica que los nombres de las clases deben empezar por mayuculas.

Comment: por curiosidad, por qué persona es privada?

Comment: @IriaPoncelaBlanco tal vez por [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(informática)).

Comment: No serviría de nada evaluar la variable directamente dentro del bloque class, no es una instrucción valida que pueda estar ahí. las instrucciones que puedes tener dentro de un bloque class varia de lenguaje en lenguaje. normalmente los bloques class tienen los atributos que tendrán los objetos que crees a partir de la clase y las funciones que definen el comportamiento del objeto ejemplo mover(),calcularSuma(),consultarRegistros()

Answer (score 4):

No entiendo por qué votan negativamente la pregunta. Aquí hay dos problemas: 
    1 - La falta de comprensión de la programación orientada a objetos; y 
    2- la familiaridad con el lenguaje.

@Daniel, debes definir qué representa esa clase, y cuál es su objetivo. Una clase puede verse como una combinación de propiedades y comportamiento. Este comportamiento está definido por sus métodos (funciones). Y las funciones utilizan las propiedades para realizar una acción.

Tu problema específico es que **estás intentando utilizar una de las propiedades de la clase y realizar una acción con ella sin que esto suceda dentro de un método**.

Para que eso funcione deberás escribir algo así:

```
 public ClasePrueba
      {
         string nombre;

         public string ConvertirAMayusculas()
             {
                 return nombre.ToUpper();
             }
      }
```

Como ves, el método ConvertirAMayusculas define un comportamiento de la ClasePrueba; retorna la cadena **nombre** en mayúsculas. **Las propiedades de una clase sólo pueden ser utilizadas en sus métodos.**

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Buena respuesta!! podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer] solo como referencia? La pregunta probablemente tiene un voto encontra porque tiene una imagen en lugar del codigo (y las imagenes no se ven bien en cualquier lado, y no se puede copiar el codigo de ellas, etc). Tambien, tene en cuenta que poner una arroba con un nombre, no sirve de nada en esta plataforma. Quien pregunto recibe automaticamente un aviso de respuesta a su pregunta. Si sirven los @ en los comentarios para referirse a alguien que participa de la conversacion.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que meter las 'variables' dentro de un método para poder usarlos, y por supuesto, tienes que hacer algo con ellas.

ej:

```
string GetPersona(){return persona;}
```

o `string GetPersonaLowerCase(){return persona.ToLower();}`

Comment: ¿Un getter privado para un miembro privado? No tiene sentido :O

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster hacer un getter asi en C# en el 2020 es tan.. 2001?

Comment: Creo que incluso en 2001 ya existían las properties ¿no? (no soy experto en C#).

Comment: Sí, cierto, pero ahora mismo no lo tiene declarado como tal y es un ejemplo para SU código, no para el uso de properties, de hecho, no pregunta por properties, sino por variables

Comment: la respuesta va bien.. yo lo que haria seria explicar el problema mas que poner un ejemplo.. el problema es que trata de usar una variable (propiedad) fuera del ambito en el cual se puede usar una variable (un metodo)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster tendria que revisar c# 1.. pero creo que si...